# Tuple type whose merged values form a type T

Tags: typescript

How to define `type Parts<T>` as a tuple holding two types `[ A, B ]` having `T extends A`, `T extends B` and `A & B extends T`

My attempt won't work properly:

```js
type Parts<T> = T extends infer A
  ? T extends infer B
    ? A & B extends T
      ? [A, B]
      : never
    : never
  : never
type T = { a: 1; b: 2 }
type PT = Parts<T>

const should_be_ok_1: PT = [{ a: 1 }, { b: 2 }]
const should_be_ok_2: PT = [{ b: 2 }, { a: 1 }]
const should_be_ok_3: PT = [{ a: 1, b: 2 }, {}]
const should_be_ok_4: PT = [{ a: 1, b: 2 }, { a: 1 }]

const should_be_ko_1: PT = [{ a: false }, { b: 2 }]
const should_be_ko_2: PT = [{ a: 1 }, { b: false }]
const should_be_ko_3: PT = [{ a: 1 }, { c: 2 }]
```

it yields `type Parts<T> = [T, T]`.

The compiler complains of all tuple elements except for 1st of `should_be_ok_3` and `should_be_ok4`, as they are complete `T`s.

Comment: **How many keys can we expect to exist on `T`?**  If there's more than a dozen or so, then you won't be able to write this as a specific type, since it would have to be a union with 2-to-the-power-of-the-number-of-keys members.  I'm wondering if I should bother with such a union utility or if we should say "this doesn't scale with specific types" and fall back to a generic constraint instead.

Comment: Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/WkEQ9N) fit your case? If yes, I will write up the answer with explanation; If not what am I missing?

Comment: ha @jcalz good obsevation, didn't consider that! 
and - in the way I asked - it would be even worse with nested structures, right?
considering shallow types would be fine for my use case
even a constrained number of keys would be ok.
what you mean with "fall back to a generic constraint instead" ?

Comment: @wonderflame your approach may not suffer the union type explosion issue, although you implemented the solution as function instead of a type..
however, it may actually fit my use case

Comment: Given that intersections don't automatically propagate into nested properties, I don't know it would be worse, but if that's a requirement then yes it would be *much much worse*.  [This approach](https://tsplay.dev/WvkBnw) is how you'd do it with single properties and it gets very bad very quickly.  As a generic constraint I mean something like wonderflame's suggestion where the compiler infers `A` and `B` from a function inputs and then makes sure they intersect to `T`... you pretty much need a function there to infer the generic type arguments)

Comment: Anyway I'll disengage here because wonderflame has this covered I think, unless someone wants to see the exploding union version ([and I hope nobody does](https://tsplay.dev/WyopAN))

Comment: @jcalz thanks for explaining the power of two problems. By taking that into consideration I decided to use the generic function which might not be very useful in your case, but it does what is expected in more optimized way

Comment: @jcalz thanks for this instructive deep insight ! although my goal is unpracticable beyound a certain complexity boundary, you sharply answered to my original question

Comment: however, kudos to you @wonderflame, as at the end of the day I opted to implement my actual use case following your approach !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even though it is possible to implement it in original requirements following [jcalz's approach](https://tsplay.dev/WvkBnw), it is not scalable when the number of properties increases, as jcalz explained in his comment. When a certain number of properties is reached, we get the recursion limitation demonstrated in the [playground](https://tsplay.dev/WyopAN).

The optimized solution would be to have a generic function that expects two arguments: first, some part of the whole type that we are working with, and the second which are the fields/properties missing in the first one.

```
type T = { a: 1; b: 2 };
const getParts = <A extends Partial<T>, B extends Omit<T, keyof A>>(
  parts: [A, B],
) => {
  //...
};
```

Here instead of defining all possible combinations of `A` and `B`, we instead let the Typescript itself infer the respective types for `A` and `B`. In this approach, the type of `B` entirely depends on the `A` which is exactly what we need in this case.

[playground](https://tsplay.dev/WkEQ9N)